# Absolute paths needed for my assets when referenced from a non-root location

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've been searching for an answer to a problem I'm trying to solve but cannot seem to find a clear solution.

I'm using WAMP server. When I create a new website I create a sub directory in the WAMP root directory: `C:\wamp\www` e.g. `C:\wamp\www\somesite.com.au`. With each site build I always have an `includes` directory: `C:\wamp\www\somesite.com.au\includes` which contains all the global snippets that each site page needs e.g. an include which contains the HTML Head contents:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sitename.css">
<!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css"><![endif]-->
<!-- All JavaScript at the bottom, except for... -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="js/libs/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script src="js/libs/respond.js"></script>
```

Problem is when I'm calling an include file from a page within a sub-directory e.g. `C:\wamp\www\somesite.com.au\profile\foo.php` using a PHP include: `<?php include("../includes/template/html-head.php"); ?>` any paths to assets in that include e.g. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">` won't be found as the paths are relative to the `includes` directory.

Is there a way using PHP or .htaccess to make any relative paths to assets in my `includes` directory always resolve no matter where I'm calling the include file from? I don't want to have to modify any code when I upload to production and do not want to use the HTML `<base>` element.

Just a note: I'm a front end developer so my PHP / .htaccess skills are extremely basic.

Cheers

Comment: you means 'css and js` files are not included on your page even that header page is included

Comment: Yes that's exactly it. the contents of `html-header.php` come through fine as I'm in control of the path to that include no matter where I am within the site: `<?php include("../includes/template/html-head.php"); ?>` however within `html-header.php` are links to assets e.g. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">` which won't come through if I'm not in the root as the path to those assets is relative to the include file. So I need any links to assets in my `includes` directory to be absolute but I don't want to have to do this: `http://localhost/_Inception/css/sitename.css`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [`dirname`](http://fr.php.net/dirname) function and [`__FILE__`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) constant

using those two items you can know where you are all the time

```
$currentScriptDir = dirname(__FILE__);
```

Note: If you are under PHP 5.3 >= there is a [`__DIR__`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) that is directly the directory where the script is sitting in

Comment: Thanks. Would you be able to provide an example of how I'd integrate the `dirname` function and `__FILE__` constant into my site? Sorry really not very clued up on PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You should link to your every asset in page by absolute:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="localhost/yourfolder/css/style.css">`

And of course you should do this for every image that you are going to put in the page. Simply define a `ABSPATH` constant first and use it around the application. But if your images are defined in style-sheet file you needn't to define them as absolute just define the absolute path for their style sheet file which I mentioned up here.

**ABSPATH:**
Usually web applications that they have user-friendly URLs for example should use absolute paths to point to their data. For instance, I got use to make a `.htaccess` file and return every call to my first page which is index.php, then I'll get the `REQUEST_URI` and separate the path to pieces and decide what part should I show to my user. It's the idea of `ABSPATH` and I define it in construction method of my core class. It can be accessed through every script in your working project. I think it's the only way to get your data to your page.

Comment: Thanks but I want to avoid using absolute paths like so: `localhost/yourfolder/css/style.css` because then I need to change those paths when I'm ready to upload to the production server. Can you elaborate a bit more on the `ABSPATH` constant you mentioned?

Comment: Thanks for extending on your answer but as I'm a complete novice with PHP I'm struggling to implement what you've recommended, I get the concept but just where to write the PHP code and how to call it.

Comment: If I tell you that you should learn more about PHP, You may become mad at me but the aim is to advice. If you want to get it quick, I can tell you just define a constant at the top of very first script in your system with the `define()` method and then value it with `$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]` then use your defined constant in entire of your application.

Comment: I've been doing my best trying to find this solution by myself before coming here, just as I always do, I'd rather figure it out myself, believe me this was the last resort. It seems like there's been a lot about this subject on Stackoverflow. I wish I could code PHP like I can code HTML, CSS and jQuery but I can't as my skills lie firmly with front end web development not back end development. I thought this was the place to come for solutions not just advice but maybe I'm wrong? Anyway appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing to get it to work:

1. Created a `config.php` file in the root and linked to it at the top of every page:

Here's the contents of my `config.php` file:

```
<?php

/* Absolute paths to the site root */
define( 'ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/' );
$path = '/Sitenamehere';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
```

I have to update the `$path` value when I upload to the production server. I'd rather not do this but not sure how to keep it universal?

1. Then for any links to assets within my includes files I link to them like this:

   href="/css/style.css">"

All works fine but not sure if how I've set it up is the best way? Also which is better to use for calling my includes:

```
<?php include (ABSPATH . "/includes/global/html-element.php"); ?>
```

or

```
<?php include "includes/global/html-element.php" ?>
```

Mainly around page performance.

Cheers

Comment: Not sure why the code block for linking to assets never came through properly? Try again: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $path ?>/css/style.css">`